# Kernel function and cudaMemcpy

Tags: cuda

I don't know why my kernel function doesn't work. Theoretically my program should display a = 14 but it displays a = 5.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

using namespace std;

__global__ void AddIntCUDA(int* a, int* b)
{
    a[0] += b[0];
}

int main()
{
    int a = 5;
    int b = 9;
    int *d_a ;
    int *d_b ;

    cudaMalloc(&d_a, sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc(&d_b, sizeof(int)); 

    cudaMemcpy(d_a, &a, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_b, &b, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    AddIntCUDA<<<1, 1>>>(d_a, d_b);

    cudaMemcpy(&a, d_a, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    cout<<"The answer is a = "<<a<<endl;

    cudaFree(d_a);
    cudaFree(d_b);

    return 0;
}
```

Also I don't understand why if I have:

```
cudaMemcpy(d_b, &b, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); //d_b = 9 on device
cudaMemcpy(&a, d_b, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost); //a = 9 on host
```

a is still 5?

Comment: Your code works for me. Output is 14. Check return type of all CUDA calls.

Comment: I realize that within the same stream this should not be an issue, but in the past I've seen strange results unless i put a cudaDeviceSynchronize() after the kernel call.  You might want to at least try that to see if for some reason the memcpy is happening before the kernel is done.

Comment: Your code completely lacks error checking. It is quite possible that the kernel didn't execute and therefore the value of a hasn't changed.

Comment: Which graphic device, CUDA Toolkit and driver have you installed? Did you try some of the examples of the CUDA SDK? In example, deviceQuery?

Comment: Thank you for your responses.   
The problem was the driver. I installed the last driver version and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you are having trouble with a CUDA program, the first step should be to use proper [cuda error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) on all cuda API calls and kernel calls.  With error checking, this error (driver issue) would have been immediately obvious.

Additional suggestions can be found on the cuda tag [info tab](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cuda/info).

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you need to put cudaDeviceSynchronize(); after AddIntCUDA<<<1, 1>>>(d_a, d_b);

When you executed AddIntCUDA<<<1, 1>>>(d_a, d_b); The host doesn't wait to the CUDA kernel if you don't put cudaDeviceSynchronize();

Comment: No, the cudaMemcpy call is a blocking call. No synchronization is necessary.

Comment: consider checking the difference between cudaMemcpy, cudaMemcpyAsync and cudaDeviceSynchronize